# Gracefully reload Apache config on Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, windows

I have an application that uses Apache (2.0.63) and mod_jk (1.2.27) as a load balancer in front of *n* number of Tomcat servers.  All of these applications are bound to Windows (I know that Apache and Tomcat are not bound to Windows, but the application running inside them is).  When you install a tomcat server we programmatically update the workers.properties file to let the load balancer know about the new server.

Currently once we update the workers.properties file we call `Apache.exe -k restart` so that Apache will pick up the new configuration changes.

I'm looking for a way to do this more gracefully.  Currently we are having problems with other parts of the application because Apache is suddenly cutting their connection on the restart.  Is there a way to gracefully reload the `workers.properties` file by sending a command to `mod_jk` or Apache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you can't. The windows apache service only seems to support shutdown and restart - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#winsvc

Answer (score 1):

Part of the output from "apache -h"

-k restart         : tell running Apache to do a graceful restart

"apache -k restart" should allow the transactions to complete.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/windows.html#signal

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the windows version, but Linux version has "graceful".

```
apache -k graceful
```

Comment: Yeah this does not exist in the Windows version of Apache.  Windows doesn't support the SIGUSR1 signal that Apache uses to do a graceful shutdown on Linux.